# iterating over json object in Jekyll to render pages with different variables

Tags: jekyll, liquid

This is a fairly standard project based on Jekyll/Liquid.  I'm trying to iterate over data object to include pages with different variables.

And since `{% include %}` and `%{ include_relative }%` tags are not permissive in terms of different symbols. This approach doesn't work:

`{% include_relative _components/ranking.html rank=ranking['rank']`

So I had to use a `{% capture %}` hack for `{% include_relative %}` to work.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" style="column-count: 3;">  
{% for ranking in site.data.infra-fund['scorecard']['rankings'] %}
  {% capture rank %} {{ranking['rank']}} {% endcapture %}
  {% capture name %} {{ranking['name']}} {% endcapture %}
  {% capture size %} {{ranking['size']}} {% endcapture %}

  <li>  
    {% include_relative _components/ranking.html rank=rank name=name size=size%}
   </li>  
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have a feeling, that this is common problem and there should be a cleaner way to write this. Maybe anyone can advise?